# Need to archive/encrypt 20GB of files

Tags: encryption, compression, 7-zip

I have 20GB of creative files (flash/photoshop/illustrator) files that i need to ship to someone.  Unfortunately, sending thru the internet isn't possible (proxy on both ends, unreliable connections, etc etc).

I decided to send DVD's with the content.  I need to know how to zip these files up, break them apart and then encrypt them.  I have 7zip installed.   How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Full details in the 7Zip help file, but something like this:

```
7z a archive.7z -p<strong password> -mhe -r -v4096m c:\path\to\stuff\*
```

would probably get you started.

```
"a" == "Add" command
"p" == Encrypt with this password
"mhe" == Encrypt headers and filenames.
"r" == recurse source directories
"v" == break archive into 4GB chunks for easy DVD burning
```

Of course, you could use the GUI as well.

**Edit**:  Assuming they're all media-type files, and therefore unlikely to compress much further, you could try

```
7z a archive.7z -p<strong password> -mhe -mx0 -v4096m -r c:\path\to\stuff\*
```

The additional switch, `m` is used to set compression level; `mx0` is "no compression, just stuff it into the archive" like `tar`.

The included help file is quite comprehensive; definitely check it out.

Comment: what would be the line to unencrypt/unarchive it?

Comment: `7z x archive.7z`; then it will prompt for the password (which isn't hidden when you enter it, by the way). If you have the GUI installed and registered for .7z files, then just double-click, and it'll prompt you for the PW.  Also, if you chunk it, the files will be named archive.7z.001, archive.7z.002, etc; they should be in the same directory when you decrypt/decompress.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend compressing them in chunks, using the 7z format, which has a higher level of compression. Use the encryption built into 7-zip. However, if your recipient does not have 7-zip or another compatible file archiver installed, or you need better encryption, use regular zip then encrypt them using [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). If you want exact chunks of compressed data, then use 7-zips native functionality to split them. (Right-click 7z file in 7-zip File Manager and select "Split File...")

Answer (score 2):

Nice answer, Adrien.

If you are sending a bunch of DVDs through the mail, you might also consider sending an "extra" DVD filled with ["parity files"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/parity_file).

That way if any one file fails its checksum, or perhaps an entire disk is damaged, the recipient can immediately use that extra disk to reconstruct the lost data, rather than waiting for you to re-send another disk through the mail.